# How to rig this puzzle

Tags: rigging, physics

I've been trying to make this fidget toy and am having difficulty rigging. Would anybody know a way to rig this. Its a closed loop like a chain. and the pieces connect with a little peg so these can only rotate on a 360 swivel. Ideally id like to be able to pose the toy with freedom like using it if possible. cant get my head around how to go about this. I had been adding two bones per segment at a right angle to one another. Or would i be better doing this using physics simulations?  [image: C]

Comment: I am not sure with this but what about curve, place those pieces on specific offset with constraint and rotate each of them around that curve?

Comment: not easy as each segment is supposed to have 2 axis I guess...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple setup, what I have made using IK:

[image]

Every bone is corresponding to one segment and one rotation:

[image]

Last bone is IK target

[image]

Last important thing is blocking all axis except Y in IK settings for every bone in chain:

[image]

Note, Rotation in IK constraint useful to detect last segment

Comment: Thank you Crantisz. This is the type of thing I'm after but making it so the segments connect so its one continuous loop  im having difficulty with and would it also be possible to have interactive points of control on each segment or possible once is connects/closed when you rotate a segment it affects the overall shape like the real model would. Thank you for your help

Comment: It is not possible to make a loop in parents, so you can make, for example, 4 chains like this and add 4 independent bones, each one to target one chain and beginning for another one.

Comment: What you can do with hooks on bones so they stick to an empty, then if its the last (or the first) doenst matter, and thus you can make loops. or use bone  constraints for it.

Comment: Thank you guys, for your reply, Crantisz, sorry i got the IK section part working fine but struggling to get the targets to work, do i create a seperate bone from the IK Target, disconnect it, and setup the beginning of the next chain to reference IK to it? cant seem to get it working. or do you just  different constraint like stretch to?

Thanks Peter. Sorry i'm not very familiar with the hooks modifier to do the distortion on orientation. sounds like a good option. but I'm not sure how to go about it, cant seem to find much on the net on something similar.

Comment: IK target should be un-parented from other bones (Alt+P)

Comment: sorry Crantisz, struggling with this, I have made the chain the same as your IK rig, and extracted a bone down from the target head, uparented it and then added an IK from the start of the new chain to this bone but cant get it to work

Comment: Hi @Crantisz,

 I've been trying the multiple sections and having the referencing each section to a target so I can get it to work that way, all works ok but on the joint where the two sections meet, this part doesn't honour the rotation rule only along the "Y" axis and tend to break causing the two pieces to intersect.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Hi @Peter

I tried the hook method but couldn't get the hook to swivel at the connect point they just tend to move the segment, couldn't find much on the net, would you mind offering a little advice?